# Card Probability Question: Drawing At Least 2 Hearts Out of 6 Cards

Tags: probability

What is the probability that a six card hand drawn from a standard 52 card deck (without replacement) has at least 2 hearts?

I set up cases for the chances of no hearts and 1 heart appearing, added their probabilities together, and subtracted them from 1, but I was incorrect.

Can anyone give me a "dumbed-down" explanation for this? It's a study guide question I want to understand.

Comment: That's the correct approach.  How did you calculate the probabilities?

Comment: For no hearts I used ( 39 * 38 ... * 34) / (52 * ... * 47). For 1 heart I used (13 * (39*...*35)) for the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right technique.   How did you calculate the probabilities?

To calculate the probability of selecting $h$ cards from the hearts, and $6-h$ cards from the other suits, out of all the ways to select $6$ cards from $52$, use:

$$\mathsf P(N_\heartsuit = h) = {\binom{13}{h}\binom{39}{6-h}\over\binom{52}{6}}$$

---

So: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(N_\heartsuit \geq 2)
& = 1- {\binom{39}{6}\over\binom{52}{6}}- {13\times\!\binom{39}{5}\over\binom{52}{6}}
\\[5pt] & =\frac{1886}{3995}
\end{align}$$

Comment: So h would equal 0 and then 1, and we subtract the obtained probabilities from 1 like I tried to do and that should be correct?